# Calculation regarding redshift and black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, gravitational-redshift

Reading this entry: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bekenstein_bound I was wondering about one calculation mentioned. They say an object that descends adiabatically to almost a black hole's horizon is seen by distant observers to lose energy from $mc^2$ to $mc^4R/8GM$. They say it's mostly due to gravitational redshift.

Quoting: *"Imagine the system in question lowered slowly (adiabatically) to very near the horizon, as in Figure 2. Accounting for the energy so extracted by the lowering agent shows that the system's energy as gauged by distant observers has been reduced from $mc^2$ to $ϵ=(mc^4R/8GM)$ (the calculation being easiest done by taking the gravitational redshift into account as described by (Misner, C W et al 1973) )"*.

I guess you should use the Schwarzschild's metric but can't see it now how to arrive to such expression. $M$ is the mass of the black hole and $R$ is the radius of the falling body.

For instance, using $\nu_{\infty} = \nu_e\left(1 - r_S/r\right)^{1/2}$, $E = h\nu$, Schwarzschild's radius and the expansion of $\sqrt{1+x} = 1+\frac{1}{2}x$ for low $x = r_S/r$ what I get is:

$$ E_{\infty} = E_e - \frac{1}{2}\frac{2Gmh}{rc^2} $$

Far from the expression of the article. Thx.

Comment: Is the $R$ in their calculation the Ricci curvature? If so, then why would you expect your expression to look at all like theirs, since it's expressed in terms of different variables? I'm also not clear on why you're using $E=h\nu$, since the expression you're trying to replicate is classical.

Comment: It's the radius of the falling body. I edit to clarify. The key is that just before entering the black hole, the energy of the falling body has decreased from $mc^2$ to $mc^4R/8GM$.